# The parameters returned by NMinimize don't correspond to the minimum returned

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to use NMinimize to solve a puzzle. Some of the code is below...

```
sumCoords = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 5, 10, 15, 19}, {1, 4, 8}, {2, 5, 9, 
    13}, {2, 6, 11, 16}, {3, 7, 12}, {3, 6, 10, 14, 17}, {4, 5, 6, 
    7}, {4, 9, 14, 18}, {7, 11, 15, 18}, {8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {8, 13, 
    17}, {12, 16, 19}, {13, 14, 15, 16}, {17, 18, 19}};
f[v_] := Total[Map[(Total[v[[#]]] - 38)^2 &, sumCoords]] + 
  10 (CountDistinct[v] - 19)^2
trueMin = {15, 13, 10, 14, 8, 4, 12, 9, 6, 5, 2, 16, 11, 1, 7, 19, 18,
    17, 3};
(* Check that the f = 0 at the known solution to the puzzle *)
f[trueMin];

params = Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, 19}];
rangeConstraint = Map[1 <= # <= 19 &, params];

steps = {};
Dynamic[ListLogPlot[steps, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True]]
sol = NMinimize[{
   f[params],
   rangeConstraint, params ∈ Integers}, params, 
  MaxIterations -> 200, StepMonitor :> AppendTo[steps, f[params]], 
  Method -> {"NelderMead"}]

sol[[1]]
f[params /. sol[[2]]]
```

The output I get is

```
15.
505
```

NMinimize returns {min, params} but why don't the parameters evaluate to the minimum. In other words, shouldn't the output lines be equal even if that is nowhere near the actual minimum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f[params/.sol[[2]]]
```

does exactly what you are telling it to. Because:

```
params/.sol[[2]]
```

gives you {13, 14, 10, 16, 1, 5, 17, 8, 11, 3, 6, 10, 13, 2, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14}.

What you want is:

```
f[params]/.sol[[2]]
```